# Сортировка потока в обратном направлении

Tags: java, сортировка, lambda, java-stream

На вход подается текстовая строка. Нужно вернуть слово с наибольшей сумой значений кодов символов. Сортировку нужно выполнить в обратном направлении. Использую метод `reversed()`, но тогда не могу использовать метод `chars()`, так как `w` типа `Object`. Как правильно осуществить сортировку в обратном порядке?

```
public static String high(String s) {

        return Stream.of(s.split(" "))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(w -> w.chars().sum()).reversed())
                .toArray(String[]::new)[0];

}
```

Comment: вместо сортировки и сборки в массив лучше использовать [`.max( .. )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)). Заодно не нужен `reversed()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static String high(String s) {

        return Stream.of(s.split(" "))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::chars, Comparator.comparingInt(IntStream::sum)).reversed())
                .toArray(String[]::new)[0];

    }
```

Данный метод первым аргументом принимает key extractor, т.е. какие данные нам нужно вытащить для сортировки, а второй аргумент принимает то, КАК мы будем сортировать. Ну то есть все просто, вытащили `IntStream` чаров и отсортировали по их сумме

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает, разобрался.